# Java Spark flatMap seems to be losing items in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I'm iterating over billions of rows in cassandra with the spark/cassandra driver and pulling out data to run statistics on. To accomplish this I am running a `FOR` loop over each row of data and if it falls within the criteria of a bucket of data i'm calling "channel" then I add it to an ArrayList in the form of of K,V pair of channel,power.

**[[Channel,Power]]**

The channels should be static based on the iteration increment of the for loop.  For example if my channels range is 0 through 10 with an increment of 2  then the channels would be 0,2,4,6,8,10

The `FOR` loop runs on the current row of data and checks to see if the data falls within the channel and if so adds it to the ArrayList Data in the format of 
[[Channel,Power]]

Then proceeds to the next row and does the same.  Once it goes over all the rows it then increments to the next channel and repeats the process.

The issue is there are billions of rows that qualify for the same channel so I'm not sure if I should be using an `ArrayList` and `flatMap` or something else since my results to be slightly different each time I run it and the channels are not static as they should be.

A small sample of data [[Channel,Power]] would be:

```
[[2,5]]
[[2,10]]
[[2,5]]
[[2,15]]
[[2,5]]
```

Notice that there my be items that are duplicate that need to remain since I run min,max,average stats on each of these Channels.

**Channel 2:**  Min 5, Max 15, Avg 8

My Code is as follows:

```
JavaRDD<MeasuredValue> rdd = javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable("SparkTestB", "Measured_Value", mapRowTo )
            .select("Start_Frequency","Bandwidth","Power");
    JavaRDD<Value> valueRdd = rdd.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<MeasuredValue, Value>(){
      @Override
      public Iterable<Value> call(MeasuredValue row) throws Exception {
        long start_frequency = row.getStart_frequency();
        float power = row.getPower();
        long bandwidth = row.getBandwidth();

        // Define Variable
        long channel,channel_end, increment; 

        // Initialize Variables
        channel_end = 10;
        increment = 2;

        List<Value> list = new ArrayList<>();
        // Create Channel Power Buckets
        for(channel = 0; channel <= channel_end; ){
          if( (channel >= start_frequency) && (channel <= (start_frequency + bandwidth)) ) {
            list.add(new Value(channel, power));
          } // end if
          channel+=increment;
        } // end for 
        return list; 
      }
    });

     sqlContext.createDataFrame(valueRdd, Value.class).groupBy(col("channel"))
     .agg(min("power"), max("power"), avg("power"))
     .write().mode(SaveMode.Append)     
     .option("table", "results")
     .option("keyspace", "model")
     .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").save();
```

My Classes are a follows for the Reflection:

```
public class Value implements Serializable {
    public Value(Long channel, Float power) {
        this.channel = channel;
        this.power = power;
    }
    Long channel;
    Float power;

    public void setChannel(Long channel) {
        this.channel = channel;
    }
    public void setPower(Float power) {
        this.power = power;
    }
    public Long getChannel() {
        return channel;
    }
    public Float getPower() {
        return power;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" +channel +","+power+"]";
    }
}

public static class MeasuredValue implements Serializable {
        public MeasuredValue() { }

        public long start_frequency;
        public long getStart_frequency() { return start_frequency; }
        public void setStart_frequency(long start_frequency) { this.start_frequency = start_frequency; }

        public long bandwidth ;
        public long getBandwidth() { return bandwidth; }
        public void setBandwidth(long bandwidth) { this.bandwidth = bandwidth; }

        public float power;    
        public float getPower() { return power; }
        public void setPower(float power) { this.power = power; }

    }
```

Comment: Hmm... I see no problem with your use of ArrayList. The flatMap function will convert each element in the list to a row in the RDD. Could you try to just count the number of rows in valueRdd (do valueRdd.count) a couple of times to verify that the data you are processing is indeed not changing from run to run?

Comment: The reason I'm concerned is because I get more accurate information the smaller set of data I pull. For example if I query 1000 rows I will get 100 channels of data that is min,max,avg but if I do a larger query of say 100,000 rows I will get something strange like 42 channels.  If anything I should have more rather than less if I query more rows. It seems like things are getting overwritten or cleared somehow.

Comment: I tried to do a valueRdd.count();  but it tells me that the count method is not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the discrepancies were do to my channelization algorithm.  I replaced with the following to solve the problem.

```
        // Create Channel Power Buckets
        for(; channel <= channel_end; channel+=increment ){ 
            //Initial Bucket
            while((start_frequency >= channel) && (start_frequency < (channel + increment))){
                list.add(new Value(channel, power));
                channel+=increment;
            }
            //Buckets to Accomodate for Bandwidth
            while ((channel <= channel_end) && (channel >= start_frequency) && (start_frequency + bandwidth) >= channel){
                list.add(new Value(channel, power));                           
                channel+=increment;
            }                   
        }
```